# Number of composite number pairs in a set

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $A = \{k : k\in\Bbb Z^+, 1\le k\le p\}$.

Let $B$ be the set of number pairs $(k, k+2)$, where both $k$ and $(k+2)$ are composite.
I want to determine $|B|$.

If $C$ is the set of composite numbers in $A$, then is it true, that 
$|B|$ = $|C|$ - $\pi$(p+2) $- 1$ or 
$|B|$ = $|C|$ - $\pi$(p+2) $-2$ ?  
where $\pi$(p+2) is the number of prime numbers up to $(p+2)$.

Because if every $k$ and $(k+2)$ were composite, then there were $|C|$ number pairs in $|B|$, but there will be a number of $(k+2)$ that are not composites, and therefore those have to be deducted from $|C|$. 
Am I right about $|B|$, or if not, what is $|B|$ ?

Comment: what is $\pi$ here? And also I think we want $B\subseteq A$, so you should mention that.

Comment: $B$ is a set of number pairs, $A$ is a set of numbers, so they are not the same "kind".
$\pi(p+2)$ is the number of primes up to $(p+2)$.

Comment: So $B\subseteq A^2$ right?

Comment: No, because $(p+1)$ and $(p+2)$ are not in $A$. If $k$ = $p$. But only these 2 elements.

Comment: $(p+1)$ is obviously composite, therefore $(p-1, p+1)$ is a composite pair, $(p+2)$ can be either prime or composite but as $p$ is prime, $(p, p+2)$ is not a composite pair.

Comment: You also have to exclude all such pairs $(k,k+2)$, where both $k$ and $k+2$ are primes.

Comment: That is included in $\pi$(p+2).